# Device::BlinkyTape::SimulationPort error: 'x' outside of string in unpack

Tags: perl

I am trying to get started using `Device::BlinkyTape::SimulationPort`, but when executing the simple example script below, I get the error:

```
'x' outside of string in unpack at /home/pi/perl5/lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape/SimulationPort.pm line 70.
```

Any idea how I can get it to work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use lib '../lib';
use Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811; # BlinkyTape uses WS2811
my $bb = Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811->new(simulate => 1);
$bb->all_on();
sleep 2;
$bb->all_off();
sleep 2;
$bb->send_pixel(255,255,255);
$bb->show();
sleep 2;
$bb->send_pixel(255,0,0);
$bb->show();
sleep 2;
$bb->send_pixel(240,0,0);
$bb->show();
sleep 2;
# Go crazy
for (my $b=0; $b<=1000; $b++) {
    for (my $a=0; $a<=59; $a++) {
        $bb->send_pixel(int(rand(254)),int(rand(254)),int(rand(254)));
    }
    $bb->show(); # shows the sent pixel row
}
sleep 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in the module.

The [Device::BlinkyTape](https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::BlinkyTape) POD `BUGS` section states:

> The device is not yet available so the module has been implemented by
> inspecting partly undocumented and unfinished code in other languages.

The module was last updated 8 years ago (2013); perhaps it is just a work-in-progress.

The module has no meaningful tests, as can be seen from the CPAN Testers results and the lack of Coverage results.  Thus, there is no public evidence that the module works.

The code posted in the Question is from the [simulate.pl example](https://metacpan.org/release/OKKO/Device-Blinkytape-0.004/source/example/simulate.pl).  Here is a minimal example which reproduces the problem:

```
use diagnostics;
use Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811;
my $bb = Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811->new(simulate => 1);
$bb->all_on();
```

I added `diagnostics` to get more information about the error.  Here is my output:

```
simulation on. at lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape.pm line 114.
'x' outside of string in unpack at
    lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape/SimulationPort.pm line 70 (#1)
    (F) You had a pack template that specified a relative position after
    the end of the string being unpacked.  See "pack" in perlfunc.
    
Uncaught exception from user code:
    'x' outside of string in unpack at lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape/SimulationPort.pm line 70.
    Device::BlinkyTape::SimulationPort::write(Device::BlinkyTape::SimulationPort=HASH(0x348b050), "\x{fe}") called at lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape/WS2811.pm line 34
    Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811::send_pixel(Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811=HASH(0x3481fe0), 255, 255, 255) called at lib/perl5/Device/BlinkyTape.pm line 137
    Device::BlinkyTape::all_on(Device::BlinkyTape::WS2811=HASH(0x3481fe0)) called at line 4
```

Here is line 70:

```
my $b = unpack("x2 C1", $color);
```

The next step is to report this [issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Device-Blinkytape) and try to get an update on the status of the module.